# Django admin panel shifts to left

Tags: django, django-admin

Just a simple question that I have no idea how to describe:

Anybody knows what has happened here?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have not run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

After upgrating to Django 3.2.

Whooa, that looks nice.